# Postgresql address specific column in variable record

Tags: postgresql, record, plpgsql

How can I address a specific field in record, or can I even define record like in Oracle for example

```
DECLARE
   TYPE timerec IS RECORD (hours SMALLINT, minutes SMALLINT);
BEGIN
-- something
END;
```

Here is example of what I mean

```
do $$
declare
radek record; -- is it posible to define elements in record, I found nothing in postgres documentation
begin
select 'c1', timestamp 'now' , 8 into radek ;
raise notice '% ' , radek;
-- I want to display/select only the middle value (time) 
-- so I need something like raise notice '% ' , radek(2)
radek := (1::int , 'text'::text, date 'tomorrow' );
raise notice '% ' , radek;
-- same case here
end $$
```

I am using different data types so array is not a solution

Comment: I don't need to create type I need to declare it in the code

Answer (score 0):

Use a column name after period. You can use aliases:

```
do $$
declare
    radek record;
begin
    select 'c1' as c1, timestamp 'now' as tstamp, 8 as eight into radek ;
    raise notice '% % %' , radek.c1, radek.tstamp, radek.eight;
end $$
```

Comment: Thanks it works, ...........I tried aliases before but only here radek := (1::int , 'text'::text /*as cl1*/, date 'tomorrow' ); and it gave me an error